# Do dropped items disappear after a while?

Tags: pubg-battlegrounds

My buddy dropped a gun and ammo for me. I grabbed the gun, forgot the ammo. We went back where he dropped it maybe 2 minutes later, and the ammo was nowhere to be found.

We were close to the area and weren't shot at, so I guess nobody just stole it.

So do dropped ammo/items disappear after a while? Or did we just suck at finding the dropped ammo?

Comment: @TimmyJim Don't answer in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing despawns, you must have just not found it.

It's easiest to see what is around you on the ground by using TAB or whatever button you have set to your inventory.

But chances are you just didn't see it/find it, smaller chances someone took it but, I've done this myself many times, it just happens.